# How to polygonize using GeoDjango and PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, geodjango, polygonize

The code of GeoDjango-1.9.2 contains reference to the function `ST_Polygonize` at:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/db/backends/postgis/operations.py#L132

But is it seems like not documented anywhere.
Is the function available for use somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This function is in the list of candidates, but not really implemented yet. As an alternative, you could use a raw sql query to get what you want:

```
qs = MyData.objects.raw(
    'SELECT *, ST_Polygonize(geom) AS polygonized FROM myapp_mydata'
)
```

The you data objects should have a `polygonized` property, the following should return a polygon:

```
qs.first().polygonized
```

Comment: in fact, with openstreetmap database, I had to use following sql:

    UPDATE relations as r set geometry=(
      SELECT st_multi(st_union(geom))
      FROM (
        SELECT (st_dump(ST_Polygonize(w.linestring))).geom
        FROM ways as w
        JOIN relation_members as m ON m.member_id = w.id
        WHERE m.member_type='W' and m.relation_id = r.id
      ) as nest
    )
WHERE r.id=%(id)s

and execute it as raw sql, using cursor.execute